# What are some notable works never translated from Latin?

Tags: history, book

I guess most, if not all, of classical-period works that have survived, were translated. But I'm certain many of the medieval era works were never published in a language other than their Latin original. Among those, I wonder which are the most prominent (at least at the time of their publish); namely those which had some noticeable impact.

Comment: Great question. If you ask anyone in medieval studies, the gap is even more dramatic: "How many notable works have a critical edition in Latin?"

Comment: Maybe lorem ipsum dolor sit amet could be a nice example, because it is not translatable at all ? : )

Comment: @d_e I think there may be some fragments of (known and unknown) ancient works only discovered in the last century, that are not translated. Does this count?

Comment: @K-HB, I would say does it not only count, but also fascinating :). now I'm curious... what works are you referring  to?

Comment: @d_e It is not really my special field, I just heard of some things: The 20th century really improved the recoverability of palimpsests (see e.g. the Archimedes Palimpsest). And in Egypt there where many discoveries of papyrus fragments. I just suspect that some of these are so new and/or niche fields, that they are not translated. If you use a fragment for textual criticism I also don't see any use in translating the raw material and not only the product of the research.

Comment: @d_e If I remember correctly they found some really used legal documents on papyri in the last decades. These are separate works and may not have all been meanwhile translated. I doubt they are "notable" though.

Answer (score 9):

One very important work seems to be never translated: The *glossa ordinaria* on the *Corpus iuris civilis*. This is the result of more than a century of work of law professors (esp. in Bolonga; caled glossators) commenting in glosses on the text of the (later so called) *Corpus iuris civilis* bundled by Accursius (d. 1263).

The *glossa ordinaria* became soon the the first resource when dealing with a question of Roman law. There was the saying: *Quidquid non agnoscit glossa, non agnoscit curia.* Until the early 17th century almost all printed editions of the *Corpus iuris* had also the *glossa ordninaria*.

---

To proof the absense of a translation is a bit difficult, but I think I can make it plausible.

I did not found any new print of the *glossa ordinaria* after 1627 (Lyon, [digitalized](https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/justinian1627bd1), linked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accursius)). There is a reprint of a edition of Venice 1488 printed in 1968ff. (Corpus glossatorum iuris civilis. Curante iuris italici historiae instit. taurinensis univ. rectore ac moderatore Mario Viora. Augustae Taurinorum) and a reprint of the Lyon 1627 edition in 2014 ([Reprint Vico Verlag](https://vico-online.net/detail/504DB/), Frankfurt am Main), but no critical edition (so explicitly [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossator); Brill's New Pauly (s.b.) does mention a repertorium of manuscripts, but no edition).

Seeing that there is no modern edition it is improbable that there is a modern translation. And in its best times everyone dealing professional with Roman law knew enough Latin to use the *glossa ordninaria*, so an old translation is improbable too.

---

Main source:

Dolezalek, Gero (Aberdeen RWG), “Glossators”, in: Brill’s New Pauly, Antiquity volumes edited by: Hubert Cancik and , Helmuth Schneider, English Edition by: Christine F. Salazar, Classical Tradition volumes edited by: Manfred Landfester, English Edition by: Francis G. Gentry. Consulted online on 09 September 2020 http://dx.doi.org/10.1163/1574-9347_bnp_e1402770
First published online: 2006 [paywall]

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the share.